# Spring 4 Hibernate 4 No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting the following exception in my web application. If you look closely, it appears to be going through the transactions managers, which means my point cuts are correct.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    com.corrisoft.air.db.HibernateDAO.getCurrentSession(HibernateDAO.java:34)
    com.corrisoft.air.db.HibernateDAO.create(HibernateDAO.java:54)
    com.corrisoft.air.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl.createPerson(PersonServiceImpl.java:44)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.createPerson(Unknown Source)
    com.corrisoft.air.ws.RememberNameController.handleRequestInternal(RememberNameController.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Here's my services.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="personService" class="com.corrisoft.air.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl" init-method="init">
        <property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- the transactional advice (what happens; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- all methods starting with get are read-only -->
            <tx:method name="retrieve*" read-only="true"/>
            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name=""/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
        of an operation defined by the serviceUpdateOperations -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceUpdateOperations"
                      expression="execution(* com.corrisoft.air.service.impl.*.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceUpdateOperations"/>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

And my data.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example"/>
        <property name="user" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="ncc-1701"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.corrisoft.air.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
    </bean>

    <!-- DAOs -->
    <bean id="personDAO" class="com.corrisoft.air.db.hibernate.PersonHibernateDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Since I saw that many of these requested an @Transactional on my service, I tried it for good measure. Didn't help.

Comment: do you have @Transactional on your DAO ?

Comment: @radai No. That wouldn't give me a unit of work, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `<tx:method name=""/>` with `<tx:method name="*"/>`.

Comment: That appears to have done it. It's at least not crashing any more. Thanks for the assist.